# Proper way to deal with only utilizing a few properties of a class?

Tags: c#

I'm adding to a fairly large program. In this program, there is a class that is mapped from our database that contains all the attributes for each employees. It has things like name, phone number, hire date, and many others; over 40 attributes in all.

Now, for my personal needs, I need to access this data, but I only need to use four or five of the attributes, not all of the ones available. I will be manipulating this "mini-object" in many ways, such as searching, returning results, and things of that nature. Here is a small, made-up example to supplement my explanation.

```
public class BigEmployee //mapped from database
{
    public string attr1 {get;set;}
    public string attr2 {get;set;}
    public string attr3 {get;set;}
    public string attr4 {get;set;}
    //...etc, until attribute 40
}

public class SmallEmployee //IF THIS EXISTED, this all that I would need
{
    public string attr1 {get;set;} //same as BigEmployee attr1
    public string attr2 {get;set;} //same as BigEmployee attr2
    public string attr3 {get;set;} //same as BigEmployee attr3
}
```

and an Example Method:

```
public List<SmallEmployee> GetAllEmployees
{
    return EmployeeList;
}
```

So, what I'm wondering, is how do I approach this problem? Should I make a separate object that is pulled from the main class? Should I just access the main class each time and force it to only return certain attributes?

Comment: if you have control over both classes, you could extract the common properties out into `SmallEmployee` and make `BigEmployee` extend it...

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should replace "attribute" with "property" in the question since your code sample contains properties (specifically auto-properties). Attributes are entirely different in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question can't easily be answered from the information that you've provided. I will try to give some general guidance, though:

It looks like your project is using some form of ORM, whether it's one of the many third-party ORM's (Entity Framework, NHibernate, SimpleData, etc.) or something homegrown. If that's the case, then there's nothing practically wrong with just creating a "lite" version of the same entity in its own class. ORM-generated classes *should* just be DTO's (data transfer objects), so there should not be any business logic contained within them. The advantage to using such classes is that, depending on the ORM, they can cut down on database traffic (since they're only bringing back the columns that you use).

**BUT** (and this is a big but)

*They are only suitable for read-only use*.

Most ORM's rely on saving an entire object or object graph back to the database. They generally do not provide a means of making changes to the database without having the original object in memory in its full ORM-compatible entity form. The most common use for these "lite" classes is for sending back large lists of objects to the user, at which point they'll select one in whatever way is idiomatic to your program, then the program will retrieve the full entity object for editing.

If what you need is full bidirectional support (retrieval alongside insert, update, and delete functionality), then you're practically limited to using the fully entity class.

**EDIT** Here's an example of using a "lite" entity:

Consider we have an entity named `Customer` in our context. We need a lite customer that only contains the ID (an `int`) and the name (a `string`). Just define a class for the lite entity:

```
public class CustomerLite
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it in a query like this:

```
var liteCustomers = context.Customers
                    .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("Smith, ")
                    .Select(c => new CustomerLite()
                    {
                        CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                        Name = c.Name
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

(or, if you prefer query syntax to lambda syntax)

```
var liteCustomers = (from c in context.Customers
                     where c.Name.StartsWith("Smith, ")
                     select new CustomerLite()
                     {
                         CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                         Name = c.Name
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: I only need it for reading and returning, I will not be adding or modifying any entries. Sorry if the information was scant, the post was getting a little long so I left out details. I'm using entity framework to map the BigEmployee table. How would I define my lite table attributes to pull from the big table, though?

Comment: In that case, a lite entity will work for you. You'll just use the normal projection syntax to select your lite entity. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a good way to do it. It's the way to go if you want to return it as a query directly from the database.

Another method would be to use interfaces:

```
public interface ISmallEmployee
{
    string attr1 {get;set;} //same as BigEmployee attr1
    string attr2 {get;set;} //same as BigEmployee attr2
    string attr3 {get;set;} //same as BigEmployee attr3
}

public class BigEmployee : ISmallEmployee
{
    ...
}
```

However, the ORM probably won't recognize this directly, so you'd have to query all `BigEmployee`'s and cast them to `ISmallEmployee` in C#.

You could also make `SmallEmployee` a base class of `BigEmployee`, you would need to take a bit of care in how you configure your ORM to interperet this.

Comment: Seems to me that the `BigEmployee` is the underlying object so even though your `ISmallEmployee` only exposes a few of the properties the underlying `BigEmployee` still loaded 40 properties...

Comment: @Lucas Yes, if you still have to query all `BigEmployee` records. The interface just suffices to simplify the result value. I've updated my answer to make that clear. I've actually used this technique when returning two slightly different types from the database which have some common properties.

Comment: Although I didn't use this method, this also would have solved my problem, if any future person decides to go this route. Thank for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.

Look up the I in SOLID 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60845/The-S-O-L-I-D-Object-Oriented-Programming-OOP-Prin

Map your main object to whatever projection your client need in this case.